# Particular choice function without Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

I have run into the following statement in Rotman, Advance Modern Algebra

> If $\{G_a\mid a\in A\}$ is a family of groups, then we may define a choice function $f:A\to\bigcup_{a\in A}G_a$ by $f(a)=1_a$, where $1_a$ is the identity element of $G_a$; we do not need the axiom of choice to define $f$. In contrast, if we merely "choose" some element $x_a\in G_a$, then the "function" $h:A\to\bigcup_{a\in A}G_a$ with $h(a)=x_a$ is not well-defined.

Intuitively, I have no problem with this statement: in the first case I am performing a kind of "determinate" or "natural" choice, because every group has an identity. In the second case, I'm really looking at the family of groups as a family of sets and hence I am really performing a choice.

However, I have been asked to show this "formally", i.e. in Set Theory, and my expertise of first-order logic is very poor.

First of all, I would like to show that the choice function $f:a\mapsto 1_a$ is well-defined without resorting to the Axiom of Choice. I know that $A$ is a set by assumption. $G:=\bigcup_{a\in A}G_a$ is a set by the Union Axiom of Set Theory and I can perform $A\times G$ which is a set. Now, I consider the formula
$$\phi:\quad \exists a(a\in A \wedge 1\in G_a\wedge u=(a,1))$$
which is an honest formula because built up from the atomic formulas $x\in y$ and $x=y$ and the constant $1$ (which exists in Group Theory) by means of the logic connectives and the quantifiers.
The choice function $f$ now should be
$$\{u \mid \phi(u)\},$$
which should mean exactly $f=\{(a,g)\in A\times G\mid a\in A \text{ and }g=1_a\in G_a\}$. Isn't it?

If that's correct, then my second question is: why I cannot use the same argument to prove that the general choice function is well-defined? Is it because in the latter case I should define $\phi$ as
$$\phi:\quad \exists a\exists g(a\in A \wedge g\in G_a \wedge u=(a,g))$$
and the critical point is $g\in G_a$? But then why exactly is it critical or in what does it differs from $1\in G_a$?

Many thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Comment: There exist many $g$ with $g\in G_a,$ so that doesn’t describe a function. The first expression doesn’t quite work either since you seem to be assuming every group has the same identity element. The key is that you have a map $a\mapsto 1_a$ since for every $a$ the identity element of $G_a$ Is uniquely specified. (And that’s really the end of it... that’s the choice function.) If you really want to get to the bottom of this logically you need to think about what it means precisely to have a family of groups and how to construct the map from one of these.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that's exactly my concern: why "choosing $1_a$" is well-defined while "choosing $x_a$" is not from a logical point of view. I'm an algebraist, mainly, whence for me "choosing $1_a$" is really meaningful. But it seems that in logic you really need to prove something.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Concerning your other observation: my problem is that in Group Theory I only have one constant symbol, which I denoted by $1$. How do I declinate this into the different identities of the different groups? I thought that the property $1\in G_a$ in formula $\phi$ would have solved the problem by saying that for the particular couple $u=(a,1)$ with $a\in A$ the $1$ I am using is exactly the $1_a$ of $G_a$. Isn't it like that? How can I state $\phi$ properly?

Comment: @EnderWiggins: But you are *given* the groups. That means that you are given this structure. In particular, you are given the assignment of which element is the distinguished element.

Comment: Yeah this is confusing, cause when one says “$x_a$” its implicit (to me at least) that we have the existence of the function  $a\to x_a$, in which case we’re already done. Where AC might be used is in the construction of such a function.  It allows you to construct a function just on the basis of the fact that the $G_a$ are nonempty... informally, we just say since for all $a$ there is an $x\in G_a$, we just choose an arbitrary one to be $x_a$. If we don’t have AC and we want a function like this we need to define *which* element of each $G_a$... if they’re groups, we can say the identity.

Comment: Formally speaking, we have “$(G, *)$ is a group implies there is a unique $x\in G$ which has the properties of the identity” and a function $a\mapsto (G_a,*_a)$ such that for each $a\in A$, $(G_a,*_a)$ is a group, so we define the set “$(a,1_a)$ such that $a\in A$ and $1_a$ is the unique element of $G_a$ that has the properties of the identity” and this set is a choice function that we’ve defined without the aid of the axiom of choice.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Let me see if I understood. Are you suggesting that the formula $\phi: \exists a (a\in A \wedge 1_a\in G_a \wedge u=(a,1_a))$ is a well-defined formula? And this because $1_a\in G_a$ is a kind of atomic formula?

Comment: @EnderWiggins It is not atomic. That formula would be an abbreviation for a somewhat long formula. But what I am suggesting is more like "exists an $a$ and exists a $z$ such that $a\in A$ and $z$ is the identity element of $G(a)$ and $u=(a,z)$." Where "$z$ is the identity element of $G(a)$" is an abbreviation that can be expanded out further. (Also I've written $G(a)$ to emphasize that it is the value of a function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that there are usually many ways (read: more than one)  to make a set into a group. So you'd need to *choose* one, given a family of sets. But in the case you're dealing with, you are *given* these choices already. So you're simply decoding from this choice a different kind of choice.

Not to mention that the axiom of choice follows from the assumption "every non-empty set has a group structure". But that's besides the point.

The thing here is that a group has a distinguished element. So it is easy to choose *that one*. Similarly, if $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of sets, then $\{A_i\cup\{I\}\mid i\in I\}$ admits a choice function: simply choose $I$ from each one. On the other hand, sets, in general, do not have a distinguished element. So you cannot just pick one in a coherent and uniform way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I sincerely don't understand it. Let's leave aside the first two paragraph for a moment: I know that groups have a distinguished element, but how does this solve the question from the point of view of Mathematical Logic? As an algebraist and a category theorist, I am convinced that if I would have been able to define a choice function I would have been working with pointed sets instead of groups in exactly the same way. But what about the formal verification of this in first-order logic?

Comment: Yes, you're right about pointed sets. The thing is that a pointed set is an ordered pair $(A,a)$ of a set, and the point. And in that sense, it's quite direct to verify that this is a choice function.

Comment: I'm convinced about that, but my question is how do I verify that that is a well-defined choice function in first-order logic and without assuming the axiom of choice? It seems that my argument above has some problems..

Comment: Well. I mean, we have $\{(A_i,a_i)\mid i\in I\}$ as a family of pointed sets. Now define $F(i,a_i)$, and that's a choice function from the family (we use the index to avoid the issue when $A_i=A_j$ for some $i\neq j$). I'll leave you to figure out the small details.

Comment: Let me see if I got your point: are you telling me that since the $G_a$'s are groups, then $1_a\in G_a$ is already a formula? And therefore that $\phi: \exists a(a\in A\wedge 1_a\in G_a\wedge u=(a,1_a))$ is a well-defined formula that I may use to show that my choice function is well-defined?

Comment: @Ender: Yes, that's about right.

Comment: To the proposer: A family $\{G_a:a\in A\}$ of groups means there exists a function $h$ on $A$ where $h(a)=<G_a,\times_a>$ for $a\in A\;.$ Now for each $a\in A$ there is a unique $h(a)$ and hence there is a unique $<a,b>$  such that $b=1_a$ is the identity for $\times_a.$ This uniqueness allows  us to use Replacement to get the existence of $S$ where $\forall a\in A\, (<a,1_a>\in S).$ Then Comprehension gives us $T=\{s\in S: \exists a\in A\,(s=<a,1_a>)\}=\{<a,1_a>: a\in A\}.$

Comment: @Daniel: You don't need Replacement here, just Separation. The reason being that the set $A\times\bigcup\{G_a\mid a\in A\}$ is a set already.